# JSF h:outputStylesheet renders nothing

Tags: jsf

This

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:outputStylesheet name="test.css" />
```

renders nothing. Do I have to add some configuration? The `test.css` is avaible in my resource folder.

Comment: still your dir structure involving the dir containing CSS is needed

Answer (score 6):

JSF injects stylesheets to either HTML head or body elements (head is the default, IIRC). For JSF to find head or body, you have to declare them as `<h:head></h:head>` and `<h:body></h:body>` (not plain `<head></head>` etc).

Answer (score 2):

JSF will inject scripts inline at the tag location if you omit the target, so using `<h:outputScript>` will work if even you don't have `<h:head>` or `<h:body>` tags. The `<h:outputStylesheet>` tag will alway inject into the head section regardless of target, so there has to be `<h:head>` elements defined in order to use that tag.